# Is it possible to change Bootstrap variables at runtime

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-5, orchardcore

I'm wondering if it is possible to change the bootstrap color variables at runtime.

I'm using Orchard Core and I would like to create a Bootstrap module where we can pick the colors in the admin area.

Then I would like to be able to call the compiled stylesheet with a controller and not with a static file because I use this in a multi tenant environment so other tenants cannot access the wrong file.

Did anyone try to do this. If so, how do you start with this.

I created a Controller that outputs a css file but that's all I have for now

Comment: Yes it is possible. Just override the css classes in a custom stylesheet.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to overwrite the bootstrap variables. I'm not planning to overwrite every class that uses the $primary variable for example